# Need Architecture advice on Azure based GPS logger application

Tags: architecture, azure, gps, azure-worker-roles

Hi I am working on Azure based GPS logger application.

The functionality include live update of location in Google maps in Web Browser and report generation

I have decided on having a WorkerRole to fetch the incoming TCP GPS data and to place it in Table (for future report generation) and a Queue (for displaying Map with latest co-ordinates through WebRole).

But leaving the Worker, Web role active the entire day and keep it waiting for the data input would be waste of resources and cost innefective.

I am expecting data to come in every 10 seconds, only few hours per day, randomly.

Is there any alternative to check for data input and start the worker role? Or is some kind of scheduling possible?

How to optimize the application.

Regards,
Anil

Answer (score 0):

I would need to understand more about your application; but there are a few things I could throw out there at the start to get you going.

How "real-time" do you need processing to be?

1) you could run an XS instance that did nothing but woke up the big worker roles. still runs when it does not need to potentially, but XS cost next to nothing.

2) check a queue with a peek from on-premises, and deploy a worker role. but that would incur a lag time of 15 minutes to deploy the role each time. because you are charged per hour, taking it down after 15 minutes only to bring it back up 15 minutes would be pointless, you may as well leave it up for the full hour.

3) scheduled task on-premises to deploy your worker role every night, read the msgs from the queue that have built up over the day, do the work, kill the deployment.

I would say solution 3 would be your best solution if the processing did not need to be "real-time"

Hope these help. else ping me and I would be happy to engage on a deeper level, or point you to somebody within our field teams to help you more.

Find me on Twitter, LinkedIn etc.

Comment: Is there any tutorial for using on-premises? How do I set the scheduler and kill the deployment?

Comment: The processing for the live display on the Google maps should be under 10 sec. Report generation can take some time.

Comment: Having the scheduler on premise defeats the high availability of azure in my opinion. You option of an xs instance to trigger the larger workers sounds like a better option to me

Comment: @MikeGoodwin Hi, could you please explain or point to how this can be done? how long would it take for an XS role to start or trigger a larger worker role?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could think to do that would be to have a monitoring process running on-prem and when it detects data, it can deploy your application to Azure to process it.  And when it is done, delete the application.  You can use the Azure Powershell cmdlets to do that, take a look at:

http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that starting and stopping your service is really going to be practical for what you want to do.  Basically you want to have your services available all the time, but don't want to pay for them.

If you're worried about cost, the only thing I can suggest is if your worker role runs on a port other than 80, run it in your web role.  By this I mean take everything you're currently doing in your worker role's RoleEntryPoint and put it in the RoleEntryPoint of the web role.  It should work without any code changes.  This way you only pay for one set of instances, not two.